# Pelican Error: u'Pelican does not know how to parse %s'

Tags: python, pelican

I'm publishing a blog using Pelican and testing my first site. 
I'm using the following command to publish on GitHub Pages:

```
make html
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR: Could not process ./.md
>
> > | TypeError: (u'Pelican does not know how to parse %s',      u'/Users        /guangyugeng/PythonProjects/virtualenvs/pelican/content/.md')

How I do to fix the error?

Comment: [.](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--g7XHnTp7--/694060475489110161.jpg)

Comment: Do you have both: markdown files in that directory, and that directory specified in `pelicanconf.py`?

Comment: yes, I add markdown after pelican-start, so markdown files not in that directory, this problem already solved, thanks!

Comment: @guangyugeng Would you consider posting an answer to this question to describe how you solved it?